# Copy selected attributes from one table to another in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

I have two SHP files, with different attribute tables.  The first is my base data, and the second is for use to import into an external modelling software package.  The base data contains a whole bunch of information not required for the model, or I need to combine data from multiple sources to generate the model files.

I want to copy data from my base data into the second SHP file, but transfer only selected attributes to the second table.  Also it would be good if I could "map" the attributes, such as:

- Base Attribute "Resvr_Name" to "Description" in second SHP
- Base Attribute "AssetID" to "id" in second SHP
- Base Attribute "Pump_ID" is not copied to second SHP

I am a novice in GIS, and am still coming to terms with the terminology and couldn't find the correct tool to do this, likely looking at the wrong area.

Ultimately I want to set up a workflow to take my base data layers and manipulate to the new layers so I can update the models easily in the future.

Answer (score 2):

To do this I think you should investigate the [Feature Class To Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) tool which:

> Converts a shapefile, coverage feature class, or geodatabase feature class to a shapefile or geodatabase feature class.

and supports field mapping:

> The Field Map parameter controls how the input fields in the Input Features will be written to the Output Features.

Answer (score 1):

In the catalog window you could right click on the layer and select load>load data you can choose the data to load, set the field mapping and use a query to load only a subset of your data. See [this ESRI help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/loading-data-in-arccatalog.htm) for more detail